# How to copy a CiviCRM/Drupal install from 1 server to another

Tags: civicrm

I've tried copying a a CiviCRM/Drupal install from 1 server to another. I copied all the files within the drupal root, and the database, and changed the database details in both Drupal's settings.php file and CiviCRM's civicrm.settings.php file. Drupal now works fine - copying this over appears to have worked, and I've done so succesfully with the same method many times. However, CiviCRM is not fully working. When I visit the main CiviCRM admin page (ie. http://cea-crm.philosofiles.com/civicrm/ on my server) I see CiviCRM's sidebar boxes (indicating it's working to some extent) but, to the right of them, see:

```
Page not found
The requested page "/civicrm/" could not be found.
```

When I click on any sidebar box link, such as 'My Contact Dashboard', I likewise see:

```
Page not found
The requested page "/civicrm/user?reset=1" could not be found.
```

Presumably I've missed some change I needed to make to reflect my new server setup? I can't *see* anything in civicrm.settings.php I still need to change, e.g. I've added lines like `define( 'CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL'      , 'http://cea-crm.philosofiles.com/' );` and `$civicrm_root = '/home/myusername/public_html/d7/sites/cea-crm.philosofiles.com/modules/civicrm';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try emptying the civicrm tables ending in _cache. There's about 4 of them. Also clear all Drupal caches in Admin->performance.

Full migration instructions are [here](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC40/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location).

Comment: Thanks! I should add there's a slightly different version of the wiki instructions you sent at http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=15052.0 which has some improvements, and hasn't been merged into the wiki yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar to this.

In my case it came right when I set up a settings_location.php file (and in the process discovered I'd copied an old one across which had some wrong settings for the new environment).

It's pretty nasty having a config file inside the module directory, but that's how it is.